# Is it possible one procedure can call another procedure inside a package body?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Question-: Is it possible one procedure can call another procedure inside a package body?(Let's i want to declare two procedure inside a **package body**(Not in Package Specification). P1 & P2 are my procedures.Is it possible P1 can call P2 inside that package body?)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you tried to do that? If I understand you correctly, you can as long as P2 is below P1 in the package body.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, otherwise packages would lose a lot of their functionality. A procedure that is defined in the package body but not in the specification is private, and cannot be invoked from outside the package; but of course can be from within.

However, the called procedure has to be defined *before* the caller within the package body source:

```
create or replace package p42 as
end p42;
/

Package P42 compiled

create or replace package body p42 as

procedure p2 is
begin
  null;
end;

procedure p1 is
begin
  p2;
end;

end p42;
/

Package body P42 compiled
No errors.
```

If you have them the other way around it won't compile:

```
create package body p42 as

procedure p1 is
begin
  p2;
end;

procedure p2 is
begin
  null;
end;

end p42;
/

Package body P42 compiled
Errors: check compiler log
Errors for PACKAGE BODY STACKOVERFLOW.P42:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ------------------------------------------
5/3      PLS-00313: 'P2' not declared in this scope
5/3      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

If you don't want to define them in that order, or can't because you have lots of procedures with dependencies that can't be organised, you can also *declare* the called procedure any time before it's used - still within the body, and using the same syntax as you would for a public procedure in a specification:

```
create or replace package body p42 as

-- declare private procedure so it can be called before it is fully defined
procedure p2;

procedure p1 is
begin
  p2;
end;

procedure p2 is
begin
  null;
end;

end p42;
/

Package body P42 compiled
No errors.
```

This is summarised [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/procedure.htm):

> Before invoking a procedure, you must declare and define it. You can either declare it first (with ***procedure_declaration***) and then define it later in the same block, subprogram, or package (with ***procedure_definition***) or declare and define it at the same time (with ***procedure_definition***).

As with a package specification, if your procedure has arguments then the declaration has to exactly match. And this is also all true for functions as well, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible for a procedure to call another.

Comment: Any examples of this? References? Anything?